# Kentico smartsearch and sharepoint online

Tags: search, sharepoint, lucene, kentico

I am attempting to set up a custom smart search index for a document library in SharePoint Online.  How do I select all of the files in a document library to be indexed?

the ISharepointListService 
has a GetListItems method, but the ISharePointFileService does not.

ex: (DataSet results = listService.GetListItems(listName);)

I need to iterate through each document and index the content and the metadata from the document library columns.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the SharePoint Client-Side Object Library (CSOM)? There's a .NET assembly version, which would be easy to use in a Kentico project. If you want to index a document library item's metadata, you need to read each list item, as you are with the GetListItems method. You can also retrieve list items using the CSOM library. There's a sample, "Retrieve items from a SharePoint list", here:

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code

However, you also want to index the content. This means each file needs to be downloaded to a temporary location and its content extracted. To get the file path from the CSOM list item, use its FileRef property. After downloading the file, the content needs to be extracted. I haven't tried this, but I'd look at using the SearchTextExtractorManager.ExtractData method. If this works, you'll have the metadata from the SharePoint list item, and the content from ExtractData. Then, you'd be able to add a document to the SmartSearch (Lucene) index.

A much easier solution would be to use a federated search approach. Instead of creating a custom SmartSearch index, the search can be executed by calling SharePoint's search API, and the results can be displayed on the same search page next to Kentico results.

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview

Mike